# Cannot POST/GET over SSL

Tags: parse-server

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install `parse-server` on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu droplet. I've also installed `parse-dashboard`.

It all works well except that I can't `curl` using `SSL`. Regular `HTTP` works fine. i.e:

```
  curl -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: AppID" https://mywebsite/parse/classes/GameScore
```

returns `Cannot GET /classes/GameScore`.

I also can't access the `parse-dashboard` over `SSL`, but `HTTP` works fine (which means my keys might leak).

POST requests return a `Cannot POST`.

I have tried enabling/disabling the firewall (`ufw`) but it doesn't change a thing.

I can save data using the SDK, though it is slow. My nginx config file is the same as in the tutorial.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Nginx config:

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - serve HTML from /usr/share/nginx/html, proxy requests to /parse/
# through to Parse Server
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name your_domain_name;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        # Pass requests for /parse/ to Parse Server instance at localhost:1337
        location /parse/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

netstat -anlp | grep 443:

```
netstat -anlp | grep 443
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN 

 -
```

Comment: Do you just get a timeout when trying to access the https site? Any errors when you restart nginx? can you curl via https on the server using localhost?

Comment: Correct re the timeout. No errors when restarting nginx. curl on localhost returns: `curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'localhost'`

Comment: Can you post your nginx config and the output of `netstat -anlp | grep 443`. This is either a misconfig and nginx isn't listening on the correct ip or a firewall is blocking

Comment: Silly question, but parse is running and responding on 1337 right?

Comment: yes. a curl on http://domain.com:1337/parse/classes/GameScore returns a valid entry.

Comment: There is an error in the tutorial. The `proxy_pass` needs to redirect to `http://localhost:1337/parse` and not `http://localhost:1337/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTTPS**
There is error in the guide, set the proxy_pass to

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/parse/;
```

and the curl request has to be done without the port 1337, like this one

```
curl -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appID" https://example.com/parse/classes/SomeClassName
```

**Dashboard**

I solved it that I **SSH Tunnel** to the server and connect to the Dashboard as a localhost, this means you dont need any credentials and it will run on http on localhost because you will be secured through the SSH Tunnel, I also turn on the Dashboard only when I need it...[how to setup SSH Tunnel](http://dokumentasifreebsd.blogspot.cz/2015/02/ssh-tunnel-in-30-seconds-mac-osx-linux.html)